# Update another table when another one is updated

Tags: php, sql

I'm not quite figuring out how to do what I'm after.So what I'm making is an online game.When a user buy's a new car I do an INSERT:

```
$c->query("INSERT INTO user_cars (carid, userid, acc, speed) VALUES ('$buyid','$id','$acc','$speed')");
```

Now I have another table that I need to insert info to right after the query above FROM the query above.What I need is the `carid` .The user can have more than 2 cars.What should I do now?

Comment: Create a trigger that uses the ID in another automated insert

Comment: Any good sites with info on triggers?

Comment: @Kirilas http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html contains good example of mysql triggers

Comment: Why don't you update the other table right after your previous one executed successfully in the same script?

Comment: @Arijoon I don't think I could because `carid` is an AUTO-INCREMENT value, and I couldn't retrieve it because the script would'nt know which carid to do...If you get me..

Comment: What method for db connection did you use?

Comment: You have the data you have just inserted! you can retrieve either the last value (highest id assuming it is AUTO-INCREMENT) or use the data to match a row and retrieve it's ID. Also you are inserting `$buyid` into `carid` column so you know it's value!

Comment: There are function in php and in sql to retrieve the last inserted id, but i agree with @juergend triggers should be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options:

1. You can build a trigger to insert a new row in table2, when row is inserted in the cars table (Read more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)
2. There is this function mysql_insert_id() which returns the last inserted id ( Read more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php )
3. If you use PDO , there is a smillar command for it
4. etc.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll go with `mysql_insert_id()` which I think is a lot easier.

Comment: @Kirilas mysql_ functions are deprecated, however

Comment: @Kirilas , Brian is right, you should change to mysqli or even better to PDO, which will help you alot when the project gets bigger

Comment: `$insertedid = $c->insert_id;` that's what I did.

Comment: @Kirilas You will have to put that on every single page that does an insert into the table (or have it in an include), which is why a database solution would be preferable to a PHP solution. A database solution is a one-time thing and then you never have to worry about it in your PHP files.

Comment: I only needed this for one query.So it's a lot easier than other solutions.Super ease and super fast.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic demonstration of the trigger you would want to create. For illustrative purposes I've also included the ddl and an example insert into your user_cars table to show that another table, which I've called "your_other_table" receives the insert (just the carid value) of an insert going into the user_cars table.

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f76a7/1/0

(notice how "your_other_tabe" has one row with the carid of the insert into "user_cars", despite having no direct inserts into itself)

```
delimiter //

create table user_cars
(
 carid int,
 userid int,
 acc int,
 speed int,
 constraint id_pk primary key (carid, userid)
)//

create table your_other_table
(
 carid int
)//

create trigger your_trigger_name before insert on user_cars
    for each row begin
        insert into your_other_table (carid)
             values (new.carid);
end
//

insert into user_cars values
(1, 2, 3, 99)//

delimiter ;

select *
from your_other_table;
```

**Output:**

```
| CARID |
|-------|
|     1 |
```

This is the only portion of the above sql that creates the trigger:

```
delimiter //

create trigger your_trigger_name before insert on user_cars
    for each row begin
        insert into your_other_table (carid)
             values (new.carid);
end
//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I got it working with just two lines of PHP, with `$mysqli->insert_id;`

Comment: @Kirilas The choice is obviously up to you but I think a trigger is more aligned with what you want to do. The majority of the above code is just creating the table and inserting an example row (which is just for illustration and not related to the creation of the trigger). The creation of the trigger is just a couple lines of code, and is on the database side, where it should be, not on the code of your page.